# Communication between the app and the web when creating web apps in an Android environment

Tags: android, web-applications

We are creating a web app using the reactive native webview. We use the method for communication between the reactive web and the reactive native app. In ios, both transmission and reception work well, but in Android, when the app sends a message to the web, it is not good to receive it. How should we solve this? Attached is the written code.

< react receiving code >

```
useEffect(()=>{
    window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage("onLoad");
    window.addEventListener('message',(e) => handleUserInfo(e))
    document.addEventListener('message',(e:any) => handleUserInfo(e.data));
},[window?.ReactNativeWebView])
```

< index.t.ds code >
`

```
declare const webkit: Webkit;

interface Window {
    webkit: Webkit;
    /**
     * A convenience API that we seem to expose in iOS.
     * Not sure whether Android does the same.
     * @see: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/25552977852427cf5fdc7b233fd1bbc7c77c18b0/ios/RNCWebView.m#L1128-L1146
     */
    ReactNativeWebView: {
        postMessage(msg: string): void;
    };
}

interface Webkit {
    messageHandlers: {
        /**
         * Added due to our call to addScriptMessageHandler.
         * @see: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/25552977852427cf5fdc7b233fd1bbc7c77c18b0/ios/RNCWebView.m#L1244
         */
        ReactNativeWebView: {
            postMessage(message: string): void;
        }
        /**
         * Added due to our call to addScriptMessageHandler.
         * @see: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/25552977852427cf5fdc7b233fd1bbc7c77c18b0/ios/RNCWebView.m#L214
         */
        ReactNativeHistoryShim: {
            postMessage(message: string): void;
        }
    }
}
```

`

< react native code >

```
`const onMessage = (event: WebViewMessageEvent) => {
    const data = event.nativeEvent.data;
     switch (data){
       case "onLoad":
  webVżewRef?.current?.postMessage(JSON.stringify({...userInfo, 
      top:insets.top, bottom:insets.bottom}));
       break;
`
```